Unable to Select Option from Material-UI Select Component - timed out retrying after 4000ms
I'm encountering an issue while writing integration tests for a React component using Cypress. Specifically, I'm facing difficulties selecting an option from a Material-UI Select component within a dialog, despite being able to login and open the dialog successfully.
Here's the error message I'm receiving:
Assert: expected '' to to equal Rxx.

The React application is serving the frontend for a Corda network, which is running in a kubernetes cluster. I am using skaffold to deploy the dev environment to the cluster.
Here's a simplified version of the dialog component:

          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <FormikFormControlSelect
                formik={formik}
                label="Insurers"
                id="insurers"
                variant="outlined"
                dataCy="insurers"
                fullWidth
                multiple
                disabled={promiseInProgress}
              >
                {memberships.insurers?.map((membership, index) => (
                  <MenuItem key={index} value={membership.identity}
                  >
                    {membership.identity}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </FormikFormControlSelect>
            </Grid>
    

and this is my test code:
describe('MachineDialog', () => {
  it('should add a new machine successfully', () => {
    // Login
    cy.visit('https://xx.xx.xxx.xxxxxx.com/machines');
    cy.get('input#username').type('xxx');
    cy.get('input#password').type('xxxxxxxx');
    cy.get('input#kc-login').click();

    // Go to machines page and open New Machine btn
    cy.get('[data-cy="new-machine-btn"]').click({ force: true });

    cy.get('#insurers-select', {timeout:5000)   // increase don't reduce 
    timeout
  .parent()
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()                              // don't force click

   cy.get('[aria-labelledby="insurers-label"]')
  .as('options')
  .find('li')
  .should('have.length.gt', 0)       // make sure the options are loaded

cy.get('@options')     
  .contains('li', 'Rxx)')   // select it
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()

cy.get('#insurers')
  .find('input')
  .invoke('val')
  .should('eq', 'Rxx')  
}

runtime DOM:

index-b28d6e1f.js:133631 Error:     AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected '' to equal Rxx

              > cy.get(@insurers-select, [object Object])
    at Context.eval (webpack://xxxxxx.com/./cypress/e2e/machineDialogInt.cy.ts:49:62)
    at runnable.fn (https://xxxxxx.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:138678:19)
    at callFn (https://xxxxxx.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:157289:21)
    at Runnable.run (https://xxxxxx.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:157276:7)
    at <unknown> (https://xxxxxx.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:163200:30)
    at PassThroughHandlerContext.finallyHandler (https://xxxxxx.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:4072:23)
    at PassThroughHandlerContext.tryCatcher (https://xxxxxx.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:1807:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (https://xxxxxx.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:1519:31)
index-b28d6e1f.js:133631 Actual:    0
index-b28d6e1f.js:133631 Expected:  0

(webpack://xxxxxx/./cypress/e2e/machineDialogInt.cy.ts:49:62)
    at runnable.fn (cypress_runner.js:138678:19)
    at callFn (cypress_runner.js:157289:21)
    at Runnable.run (cypress_runner.js:157276:7)
    at <unknown> (cypress_runner.js:163200:30)
    at PassThroughHandlerContext.finallyHandler (cypress_runner.js:4072:23)
    at PassThroughHandlerContext.tryCatcher (cypress_runner.js:1807:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (cypress_runner.js:1519:31)
logError @ index-b28d6e1f.js:133634
(anonymous) @ index-b28d6e1f.js:145969
emit2 @ index-b28d6e1f.js:139329
(anonymous) @ cypress_runner.js:182180
emit @ cypress_runner.js:146549
emit @ cypress_runner.js:182243
onPrint @ cypress_runner.js:200038
_onPrintClick @ cypress_runner.js:200042
(anonymous) @ cypress_runner.js:199743
executeAction @ cypress_runner.js:180885
n @ cypress_runner.js:180885
ca @ cypress_runner.js:245
ja @ cypress_runner.js:246
ka @ cypress_runner.js:246
wa @ cypress_runner.js:248
Aa @ cypress_runner.js:249
ya @ cypress_runner.js:249
Da @ cypress_runner.js:252
Ad @ cypress_runner.js:315
Gi @ cypress_runner.js:481
Kb @ cypress_runner.js:270
Dd @ cypress_runner.js:317
(anonymous) @ cypress_runner.js:482
exports.unstable_runWithPriority @ cypress_runner.js:537
Ii @ cypress_runner.js:482
Cd @ cypress_runner.js:316

html elements in DOM while no options has been selectd:
<div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-12">
  <div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiFormControl-fullWidth" id="insurers">
    <label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-outlined" data-shrink="false" id="insurers-label">Insurers</label>
    <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-formControl" data-cy="insurers">
      <div class="MuiSelect-root MuiSelect-select MuiSelect-selectMenu MuiSelect-outlined MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input" role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-labelledby="insurers-label insurers-select" id="insurers-select" tabindex="0">
        <span>​</span>
      </div>
      <input aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" class="MuiSelect-nativeInput" value="">
      <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSelect-icon MuiSelect-iconOutlined" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path>
      </svg>
      <fieldset aria-hidden="true" class="jss54 MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline">
        <legend class="jss56"><span>Insurers</span></legend>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



html elements in DOM when i manually selected an option:
<ul class="MuiList-root MuiMenu-list MuiList-padding" role="listbox" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="insurers-label">
  <li class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root Mui-selected MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button Mui-selected" tabindex="0" role="option" aria-disabled="false" data-cy="select-option-Rxx" data-value="Rxx" aria-selected="true">
    Rxx
    <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
  </li>
</ul>



Would using cy.select() simplify things and work? https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select

I've already tried that as well, but still getting the same error

I'm also having the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78474427/cypress-clicking-a-mat-form-label-being-flaky?noredirect=1#comment138348535_78474427

You probably already know that Cypress tests the page in the browser, not the source code that you presented. So the question should have the partial runtime DOM for the select you are testing.

Broadly, the problem seems to be that you are not waiting for the page to respond after clicking open the dropdown.
Cypress tells us best practice is

don't chain anything after the .click()
add assertions after click to make sure page is in the settled state

It looks like the options are added after the dropdown is opened. There's a few selectors you could use for the added DOM section.
Below I chose aria-labelledby since it's value is specific to the insurers dropdown but other selectors may also suit.
cy.get('#insurers-select', {timeout:5000)   // increase don't reduce timeout
  .parent()
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()                              // don't force click

cy.get('[aria-labelledby="insurers-label"]')
  .as('options')
  .find('li')
  .should('have.length.gt', 0)       // make sure the options are loaded

cy.get('@options')     
  .contains('li', 'RuV (Wiesbaden, DE)')   // select it
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()

cy.get('#insurers')
  .find('input')
  .invoke('val')
  .should('eq', 'RuV (Wiesbaden, DE)')  // verify the value


I have tried the changes that you proposed. Again after that it cannot find the li element.

From the new HTML you posted, possible the options are added dynamically at the end of the DOM.

I gave some revised code based on the HTML you added. You can iteratively refine it after running on the live system - this is a good starting point.

Yes, options are added dynamically at the end of the DOM. I have also tried the new code that you provide and refined it and at the end find out since the select is a multiple mui select and when user click on an item, user must click outside of that select box or on another element so that selected option is really shows on the input, which is a wierd bahaviour.

so right now all tests are passed and only the last one that verify the value is not passed, because of multiple select behaviour that i mentioned already.

in the real app after selecting an option you have to click outside so that you can see the selected option. In the test i see that the item is selected but that extra click outside is not done so i guess that's why it cannot verify the value, i'm not sure how much does it make sense, but do you maybe know the reason?

For your test to simulate the user clicking outside the options, try cy.get('body').click() or cy.get('@options').blur().

cy.get('body').click() worked well.
